# google chrome .on click on dynamically generated <a> Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below script does not work as intended in Google Chrome but on Firefox it does.

Explanation: ".pagination" class is put on some links that works like a pagination but in Google Chrome (Internet Explorer as well but who cares about it) it actually go on the link then call the function which is not what I wanted. The same script on firefox works as intended.
I don't know if its the fault of the .on or the fact that the Page numbers(links with the class ".pagination" are made dynamically.

```
$(".tab_content").on("click",'.pagination', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    page = $(this).data("page");
    rePut(page);
    return false;
});
```

and Reput function

```
function rePut(var1)
    jQuery(name_tab).load("link", {page: var1},function(){
});
```

And the last edit i hope if it matters even .change() function from jquery doesn't work as intended on google chrome.

Comment: can you create the fiddle.

Comment: i will try but i have ajax aswell so i don't think i can reproduce exactly but if it works on firefox i think is just a compatible problem.

Comment: 1- page is looking like a global variable. 2- i think problem must occure inside the rePut function, can you show that? 3- why do you return false? you already have preventDefault()

Comment: Where are keeping your script in a page? Try keeping at the end of body section.

Comment: Reput Shows exactly what i want shows the html just when i click the link google chrome refreshes the page. If i go again on the tab that i have it shows what i wanted. yes, page is globally.

Comment: where is name_tab set? why use jQuery() and not just $?

Comment: Good suggestion, i will modify.

Comment: The `.tab_content` elements are static, right?

Comment: No the .tab_content elements are dynamically .tab_content the div itself its static